# Background downloading even if the phone gets locked

Tags: iphone, background, multitasking

I am trying to implement an application for iPhone that should simply download some content out of the web. This download is quite big, so I implemented the download as a background task to give the user the chance to do some other stuff with his phone while downloading. My problem is that if the user pushes the lock button (or if auto lock kicks in) the applicationWillResignActive: in the AppDelegate is called and after about ten seconds the download is aborted because the phone does not enter background and just stays inactive.

My question is what am I doing wrong? How can I ensure that the download is continued, even if the phone is locked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround the downloading code with background task block like this:

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            //here you need to finish what you are doing evven if you've not finished yet, otherwise your app will be killed
            [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        }];

        //here comes your downloading code

        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
```

This will give you 10 minutes(according to some other posts) to execute code in background...

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it just works perfectly fine when I send the application to the background via the home button. But when I press the lock button while the app is in foregrund, it just gets inactive (applicationWillResignActive: is called) but is not send to background. Therefore the background task is not processed...

Comment: Then you can try this method:
http://blog.marcopeluso.com/2009/08/23/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping/
 But I don't know if it works well and if it will be approved by apple...

Comment: Cool! I'm glad that it worked well. Let us know about approval issue :)